# How to generate unique pairs of numbers on python

Tags: python, sockets, arraylist, logic

So I’m working on a chat application right now.. let’s say we have User1, User2, User3, ...UserN. I want to generate a unique port number for each pair. Like User1 and User2 will have 5000, User1 and User3 will have 5070, User2 and User3 will have 5500, etc etc.. basically every User should have a different port number for other users.. but both of the Users should have the same one for each of them.

Comment: What do you mean each pair of users has a unique port? A port for what? You need to specify the network architecture you're envisioning: clients, servers, who talks to who and how are the connections established.

Comment: It’s a chat application and the network model is client-server-client. I want the users to be able to send personal messages to all other users

Comment: You need many more details than that. For example, will these port numbers change during the life of the application?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to map every pair
`i,j` from `User-i` and `User-j` to a number between `0` and `65535` (or whichever your range is). By the way, this means that you're going to have a maximum of `65535` pairs of users, and since there are `N * (N-1) / 2`  pairs, that means about `362` users.

But which group to map to which port?
Let's say `User-0` gets ports `1` to `N`, next user `N+1` to `2N`, etc
This way you can map `i,j` to `f(i,j) = N*i + j`, which is a 1-1 function, however `i,j` gives a different result than `j,i` , which is not what you want.
Therefore, we first need to map `i,j` to something which gives the same result for `j,i` but for no other inputs. One idea is `g(i,j) = (i,j) if i<j else (j,i)`. In other words, sort the numbers first.

Now `User1, User2` are mapped to `1,2 -> 1,2 -> 360*1 + 2 = 362`
And also `User2, User1` are mapped to `2,1 -> 1,2 -> 360*1 + 2 = 362`

Comment: I’m sorry, but I’m not sure if I understand this very well. But are you saying that 362 is the maximum number of users my application can use?

Comment: If you want one port for every pair of users, and there are 65535 ports, then yes, 362 is the maximum users. That's because 362 users make 64620 pairs.